# Pointer value in Mac OS - Get Value from queue

Tags: c, macos, struct

I've defined a struct like this:

```
typedef struct queue
{
    int front, count;
    int values[MAX];
}QUEUE;
```

And when i try to get the value in the front of the queue (passing it to a variable) i get an error: "illegal instruction:4"

The function getting the value is:

```
int front(QUEUE *q, int *x){
    int r=0;

    if(q->count==0) r=1;
    else{
        *x = q->values[q->front];
    }
    return r;
}
```

I have initialized the struct with:

```
void initQueue(QUEUE *q){
    q->front = 0;
    q->count = 0;
}
```

In fact , this compiles at a linux environment.

```
int main(){
     QUEUE queue;
     int *i; //i chose not to initialize with null

     front(&queue, i);
     printf("%d", *i);
     return 0;
}
```

What could be the cause of the problem?

PS.: I've had it run with sudo. It does not show the error, but doesn't output anything .

Thank you all for your help in advance.

Comment: How do you call `front()`?

Comment: `int front()` shouldn't compile. It doesn't `return` anything, much less an `int`.

Comment: @EOF I've written it from the top of my head, i've added more information.

Comment: @iharob, i've added that information to the post. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have undefined behavior since you do not initialize the `i` pointer in `main()`. You can't assume that `queue->count` is going to be 0 (since you don't initialize that, either), so the `else` branch in `front()` might be taken, which will then write through `x` and cause undefined behavior.

The fact that you pass a non-initialized pointer means it can never work. If it doesn't crash, that doesn't mean it's correct. Undefined behavior is undefined.

**Note:** even if you remove the call to `front()` altogether, the `printf()` still invokes undefined behavior by doing `*i` on an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: Even if i initialize, i get the same error. 

To note that, in linux environment it compiles and works as expected.

Comment: i am very thankful for all the help provided, in fact i have defined void initQueue(); that initializes the tamanho variable at zero. Added the function to the original post.